# When I install package spatstat R doesn't install it

Tags: r, spatstat

My problem is that I have tried various times to install spatstat, but R never installs it. I get an error message which is attached (doesn't let me attach the image):

```
> install.packages("spatstat.data")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/david/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
also installing the dependency ‘spatstat.utils’


  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
               binary source needs_compilation
spatstat.utils  2.3-0  3.0-4              TRUE
spatstat.data   2.2-0  3.0-4             FALSE

  Binaries will be installed
probando la URL 'https://cran.rediris.es/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/spatstat.utils_2.3-0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 374003 bytes (365 KB)
downloaded 365 KB

package ‘spatstat.utils’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
        C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpawwH0p\downloaded_packages
installing the source package ‘spatstat.data’

probando la URL 'https://cran.rediris.es/src/contrib/spatstat.data_3.0-4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2934723 bytes (2.8 MB)
downloaded 2.8 MB

* installing *source* package 'spatstat.data' ...
** package 'spatstat.data' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'spatstat.utils' 2.3-0 is being loaded, but >= 3.0.2 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace
Ej
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'spatstat.data'
* removing 'C:/Users/david/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/spatstat.data'

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpawwH0p\downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("spatstat.data") :
  installation of package ‘spatstat.data’ had non-zero exit status
```

I am using **windows 10, R 4.0.3**

Comment: Can you upgrade R and reinstall packages? Your CRAN mirror has more up to date binary packages for spatstat for the latest R version.

Comment: @Spacedman many thanks for your advice. I have done it and I have installed without a problem spatstat library.